# Using LDAP with HornetQ

Tags: security, ldap, jaas, hornetq

HornetQs default SecurityManager (HornetQSecurityManagerImpl) will check users/roles that are stored in the hornetq-users.xml. I want use LDAP for authenticating users; I have two ways:

1. Using Jass, and use it with LDAP for authenticating users.
2. Implementing SecurityManager interface manualy, and using LDAP in my own security manager implementation.

Which one is better? Other approaches? What should i do? (experience, sample)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's always better to use something that's ready and tested. Using JAAS with Ldap will give you an easier path as that should work nicely.

On the hornetq's distribution there's an example showing how to configure JAAS. You can just get the distribution zip at http://www.jboss.org/hornetq/downloads.html and refer the the examples that are part of hornetq already.

Comment: let me know if you have specific questions and I can post-edit my answer to help you better.

Comment: Thanks Clebert; Documents (part 31.5 in 2.3.0.CR2) said: Hornetq implemented jaas in org.hornetq.integration.jboss.security.JAASSecurityManager. So  for using ldap with jaas, i should implement the required interfaces, and put them in classpath of hornetq?

Comment: And where is org.hornetq.integration.jboss.security.JAASSecurityManager class?

Comment: Just use the class, no need to implement a new one:

The class is at hornetq-core.jar

this will help you next time:

find . -name \*jar -exec unzip -l {} \; > list.txt